# Tauri how to disable the top bar menu windows restore minimize maximize move size

Tags: javascript, tauri

In Tauri, do you know how to disable the top bar menu (i.e. restore, minimize, maximize, move and size?

When right-clicking on the top bar of the app I don't want the user to be able to close the app by mistake.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do has been [merged](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/commit/c4d6fb4b1ea8acf02707a9fe5dcab47c1c5bae7b) recently in tauri v2. I am not sure about the relationship with tauri v1, but I tested the config and it works in my Tauri 1.4 app, so it should work in yours as well, provided you have a recent enough app.

You have to add your `tauri.conf.json` this option:

```json
{
  "tauri": {
    "windows": [
      {
        "closable": false,
        "maximizable": false,
        "minimizable": false,
        "resizable": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

to all the windows that you want to miss the `Close` and related buttons. Note that `resizable` seems to have been supported longer than the others.

I have tested the code in [my example Tauri app](https://github.com/tachyonicbytes/so-answers/blob/721407f6acc6d120e71cfdab289c16dfe91673f3/77524788/tauri-app/src-tauri/tauri.conf.json#L51), and for me, on Ubuntu with Gnome and X11, the `Minimize` button does not disappear. The comments in that commit also mention that some of the changes are best effort, not everything may work on every platform.

Note, from that same commit, that you can also change the `closable` and other settings from the frontend:

```js
import { appWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window';
await appWindow.setClosable(false);
```